# gnuplot label using other values than the ones used for the plot

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot a label for my axis x that is not related to the values used for the plot.

Let's say my data is in a file.txt looking like :

```
toto 0 1 23 56  
tutu 0 2 45 67  
tata 0 3 67 23  
tete 1 4 12 56
```

and what I want is a display of column 4 and 5 values using column 3 as the x axis :

```
plot "file.txt" u 3:4 title "colum4_values",\  
"" u 3:5 title "colum5_values"
```

but I'd like to have the values of the column 1 displayed along the bottom X axis (xlabel) and the values of the column 2 displayed along the top X axis (x2label).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the values of a column as tic labels, you can use `xticlabels` (short hand is `xtic`) or `x2tic`:

```
set x2tics
set xtics nomirror
plot 'file.txt' using 3:4:xtic(1) title 'column4_values',\
     '' using 3:5:x2tic(2) title 'column5_values'
```

Usually, to plot on the `x2`-axis, you need to use `axes x2y1`, but when using `x2tic` this seems not to be necessary. You only need to enable the tics on the second axis with `set x2tics`.